# jeditable placeholder issue

Tags: php, jquery, jeditable

I am using jeditable, the place holder is a text. I am trying to have it where after I edit the box the placeholder is the text that I typed. not the actual text "click to edit"
on the demo site after you edit the input box "click me if you dare" it will show what u typed.i copied the js and used it but it doesnt behave that way. any hint/guidance would be greatly appreciated. (the field name is notes and its pulled using an sql statement. save.php does an UPDATE on that same field.)

demo: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html 
jeditable.js:

> http://www.appelsiini.net/download/jquery.jeditable.js

```
var e = jQuery.noConflict();
  e(".click" + zid).editable("http://www.site.com/save.php", { 
        id   : 'did',
         name : 'nvalue',
      indicator :  'Saving...',
      tooltip   : "Click to add/edit notes",
      style  : "inherit",
      width      : '630px',
      onblur     : 'submit',
     placeholder: 'click to edit',
      type   : "textarea"
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your saving script must echo back the string you want to display on webpage. Jeditable displays the default placeholder if saving script does not return anything.

Answer (score 1):

This example might help:

```
<?
//$error is an array that stores previous validation errors
//$id and $value contains default jeditable's $_POST values
//so, if no errors found...
if(count($error)<=0){
    //save
    $query = mysql_query( "UPDATE {$table} SET {$field}='{$value}' WHERE id='{$id}'");
    //print value so it displays/updates
    print $value;
}else{
    //Errors found, here i just echo each one of them, then I can use jeditables's
    //"onerror:" callback to display or do stuff...
    header("HTTP/1.1 406 Error");
    foreach($error as $err){
        echo $err.' - ';
    }
}
?>
```

Cheers!